# Google Oauth2 - redirect_uri_mismatch despite being set up

Tags: php, google-oauth, redirect-uri-mismatch

I am trying to run the Oauth2 stack in our google development project, but I keep getting the error:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

In the console, I have defined these two "Authorized redirect URIs":

```
https://edit.<MY DOMAIN>/oauth2callback
https://<MY DOMAIN>/oauth2callback
```

(I added the second to try and get around the problem). The URL I'm going to for oauth is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&
access_type=offline&
client_id=<MY CLIENT ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fedit.<MY DOMAIN>%2Foauth2callback&
state=host%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwebhosts.<MY DOMAIN>%2F-%2FControlGoogleAnalytics%2Foauth2callback&
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.edit%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&
approval_prompt=force&
include_granted_scopes=true&
login_hint=<MY LOGIN HINT>
```

Which seems to be correct, but I am getting the uri mismatch error, even an hour or so after I added the Redirect URIs in the google cloud console. Is it just that I have to wait longer?  Or did I miss something?

My PHP code at this point is dead simple. There is a form that lets me pass in a google account name that I have already created (andy3.ihouseweb@gmail.com) so I can use it as a login hint, then:

```
$google_user_account_name = <validated account name string>;

$this->google_oauth_url = $createAuthUrl() . \
    "&login_hint={$google_user_account_name}");

$this->redirect( $this->google_oauth_url );
```

The generated oauth_url at this point is:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=<CLIENT ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fedit.elite80-001.ihousedev.com%2Foauth2callback&state=host%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwebhosts.elite80-001.ihousedev.com%2F-%2FControlGoogleAnalytics%2Foauth2callback&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.edit%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&approval_prompt=force&include_granted_scopes=true
```

The redirect URIs in the console include:

```
https://elite80-001.ihousedev.com
https://www.elite80-001.ihousedev.com
https://edit.elite80-001.ihousedev.com
https://edit.elite80-001.ihousedev.com/oauth2callback
```

I think that the first 3 are unnecessary, but I was trying everything I could think of...

Comment: check the error message you should be able to click a link for details it will tell you the exact redirect uri you need to add

Comment: Unfortunately not. The error message is "Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid", continuing with:  You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue.
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch.  Clicking on the link (error details) Just pops up a window that says:  "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch".   8-(

Comment: Are you getting the error when you go to this authorization dialog URL, or are you getting it afterwards, when you system tries to exchange the code for a token? I am suspecting it is the latter; in which case, make sure that that API request uses the exact same `redirect_uri` value, you used in your login dialog request.

Comment: can you include your php code

Comment: I'm getting the error going to the authorization URL. I am updating my question to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found that the problem was that my database had been altered, and the clientId was incorrect. Don't know why I didn't catch that sooner. I identified the correct Oauth client and downloaded the json file, installed it, and now I am onto the next problem. Thanks all.